# Easier way work with database in windows phone 8

Tags: database, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to work with sql server compact database in my windows phone 8 project. 
For now the only way of doing this is by using SQL to LINQ with database SQL sever compact 3.5. The worst is that the SQL to LINQ should be code-first and this produces a lot of problems. Example for simple application with database can be found here:

[Example1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx)
   [Example2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405(v=vs.105).aspx)

Please give me some another example or write it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a look [Here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone) and [Here](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8-a-sqlite-net-version-for-mobile/). These links help me a lot to use sqlite in wp8 application.

Comment: Very good variant, it seems to work fine, but in my case there is problem with locating the database file. I mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The variants for resolving the problem gived by Jaihind are good, but for my project, there are problems with locating the database file. I recomend to the readers to download this code sample and review the documentation: [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671).